# Julia: limited printing of large arrays

Tags: arrays, printing, julia

I produce a number of large arrays in Julia using a script file. Printing out the whole array is cumbersome but I'd like to check the first few rows make sense.

I know in the REPL there's printing which is limited by the screen size e.g.

```
julia> zeros(1000,10)
1000×10 Array{Float64,2}:
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
⋮                        ⋮                      
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

But I can't find any print/show function in base Julia which mimics this for scripts, say only printing out the first 10 rows of an array or something like R's `head` (I would have expected `showcompact` to do something like this).

Is there an analogous function to R's `head` in Julia or do I have to write my own.

Comment: You should use IOContext for this.

Comment: Julia `>=1.6`: `first(x, 1)` is your `head` equivalent and `last(x, 1)` your `tail` equivalent. See: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.first

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the way to do this in v0.5 is to use an `IOContext`.

A very simple way to limit the data is to pass the `:limit => true` parameter to the `IOContext`;

```
julia> show(IOContext(stdout, :limit => true), v)
[0.147959 0.414018 … 0.595528 0.852563; 0.32679 0.824953 … 0.432143 0.036279; … ; 0.877398 0.661854 … 0.197207 0.15596; 0.0522946 0.508075 … 0.835359 0.705987]
```

But this still does not print out the way the REPL does; that's because `show` with two arguments uses a single-line display. To use a multiline display, pass `text/plain` as the second argument to `show` (a MIME type):

```
julia> show(IOContext(stdout, :limit => true), "text/plain", v)
100×100 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.147959   0.414018   0.0282934  …  0.816132   0.595528   0.852563 
 0.32679    0.824953   0.0582351     0.822526   0.432143   0.036279 
 0.754989   0.724317   0.533966      0.987273   0.931932   0.973622 
 0.547866   0.282694   0.0295411     0.75929    0.886218   0.0813057
 0.0626663  0.111795   0.625083      0.439983   0.562143   0.669046 
 0.712093   0.469622   0.377298   …  0.298224   0.31853    0.376066 
 0.774625   0.754328   0.756725      0.61113    0.76566    0.999292 
 0.917846   0.308363   0.489246      0.715311   0.175302   0.124059 
 0.310922   0.140575   0.20635       0.0280192  0.683004   0.168129 
 0.753361   0.755103   0.831806      0.118009   0.122374   0.281476 
 ⋮                                ⋱                                 
 0.420264   0.7614     0.748408      0.330983   0.0776789  0.309464 
 0.984379   0.851735   0.595121      0.534982   0.255317   0.743713 
 0.814505   0.765941   0.71852       0.730677   0.477631   0.0360992
 0.910384   0.0747604  0.490685      0.0904559  0.0756424  0.313898 
 0.628416   0.0790874  0.401488   …  0.523521   0.397249   0.58112  
 0.578361   0.336352   0.261118      0.838256   0.387374   0.451647 
 0.66724    0.586342   0.378968      0.602694   0.450686   0.901279 
 0.877398   0.661854   0.685156      0.658952   0.197207   0.15596  
 0.0522946  0.508075   0.244423      0.95935    0.835359   0.705987
```

You can of course change how many rows are shown by passing in `:displaysize` to the `IOContext`:

```
julia> show(IOContext(stdout, :limit => true, :displaysize => (10, 10)), "text/plain", v)

100×100 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.147959   …  0.852563
 0.32679       0.036279
 0.754989      0.973622
 ⋮          ⋱          
 0.877398      0.15596 
 0.0522946     0.705987
```

Overall, `IOContext` is very flexible. See its [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/) for more details.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: This is the first understandable example of IOContext that I've seen. +100!

Answer (score 4):

You could easily define a `head` function yourself. For one and two dimensions, this is pretty straightforward:

```
torange(n::Integer, m) = 1:min(n, m)
torange(c::Colon, m) = (:)

function head(a::AbstractArray{TypeVar(:T), 1}, n = 10)
    view(a, torange(n,size(a,1)))
end


function head(a::AbstractArray{TypeVar(:T), 2}, n1 = 10, n2 = 10)
        view(a, torange(n1, size(a,1)), torange(n2, size(a,2)))
end
```

The `torange` method allows to use a `:` to return the full length in the corresponding dimension. For example

```
head(zeros(10, 10), 5, :)
5×10 SubArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},Colon},false}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

For more than two dimensions, I have chosen to repeat the last argument beginning from the third:

```
function head{Na, Nn}(a::AbstractArray{TypeVar(:T), Na}, n1 = 10, n2 = 10, ns::Vararg{TypeVar(:T), Nn} = 2)
        nend = last(ns)
        view(a, torange(n1, size(a,1)), torange(n2, size(a,2)), (torange(ns[i], size(a,i+2)) for i = 1:Nn)..., (torange(nend, size(a, i)) for i in Nn+3:Na)...)
end
```

For example:

```
head(rand(10, 10, 5, 5), 3, 3, 2)  # the last two is the default value and can be omitted
3×3×2×2 SubArray{Float64,4,Array{Float64,4},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}},false}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.384724  0.7328   0.585211
 0.738284  0.95145  0.362914
 0.43928   0.94307  0.758541

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 0.78603   0.588877  0.677201
 0.559547  0.800559  0.488433
 0.993593  0.691884  0.236595

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 0.25732   0.90491   0.323905
 0.300924  0.703919  0.813316
 0.040522  0.776142  0.624097

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 0.746677   0.153574   0.155539 
 0.991624   0.90167    0.0880094
 0.0423263  0.0153597  0.0608328
```

Note that the n-dimensional version is not type-stable, but that shouldn't matter for printing.

Comment: Aah that is a good way of doing it. Do you know if there is a base method that does limited printing in Julia?

Comment: I don't know. It would be nice if the default maximum printing length of the head and tail could be set for each dimension at the beginning of a script or session.

Comment: In `Julia 1.6+` you can use `first(x, 10)` and `last(x, 10)`.

Answer (score 4):

We can get the same output as REPL by using `display()` (is this what you are looking for...?) Also, the "head" and "tail" parts can be printed by using array sections, e.g.,

```
disp( x ) = ( display(x) ; println() ; println() )

A = diagm( [ i for i=1:100 ] )

disp( A )
disp( A[ 1:5, : ] )         # head
disp( A[ end-4:end, : ] )   # tail

B = [ i for i=1:100 ]

disp( B )
disp( B[ 1:5 ] )         # head
disp( B[ end-4:end ] )   # tail
```

---

```
$ julia test.jl

100x100 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  …  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0   0  0  0  …  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  10  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 ⋮              ⋮               ⋮     ⋱                   ⋮                 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0     92   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0  93   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0  94   0   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0  95   0   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  …  0   0   0   0  96   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0  97   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0  98   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0  99    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  100

5x100 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  … 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

5x100 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  … 0  0  0  0  0  96   0   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0   0  97   0   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0   0   0  98   0    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0  99    0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0  100

100-element Array{Int64,1}:
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
  10
   ⋮
  92
  93
  94
  95
  96
  97
  98
  99
 100

5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  96
  97
  98
  99
 100
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the best option, though as tim said would be nice to set a default on the maximum printing length

Comment: Yeah I agree, and I also write a custom pretty-print routine that has more control. But for simple cases display() is OK for me.

Comment: Though I don't seem to get the 'auto limits' with the ... notation as you do. I'm using Julia 0.5. So I'll have to just try and define my own function.

Comment: Ohhh, right, if I use v0.5, I did not get such "..." thing but a full list of numbers.... (I used v0.4.7 in the above test). Hmm..

Comment: Aah right so maybe it's an issue with v0.5! It might be worth raising the issue on github...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this thread is out of date. For me on julia v1.4.1 , the display function does not print a limited array, and

```
a = zeros(1000,6)
show(IOContext(STDOUT, limit=true), "text/plain", a)
```

yields an error. Instead I found this works

```
a = zeros(1000,6)
show(IOContext(stdout, :limit => true), "text/plain", a)
```