# Julia: which environment variable/setting controls the number of elements printed for an array in the repl?

Tags: julia, display, read-eval-print-loop, pretty-print

When I print

```
rand(1_000_000)
```

It prints the first `N` lines and prints the last `N` lines. How is this `N` determined and how do I control this `N`?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if there is an API for setting these values, but this is determined by `show` which uses `displaysize` on the `IO` object. You can get your terminal display size with: `displaysize(stdout)` for example.

Comment: @SalchiPapa I would accept this as the answer.

Comment: You can use `IOContext` to control `displaysize`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia: limited printing of large arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788316/julia-limited-printing-of-large-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size comes is calculated by `Base.displaysize(::IO)`, which you can see should report the size of your terminal for `stdout`, and reports the "standard" size for IOBuffers:

```
julia> Base.displaysize(stdout)
(19, 81)


julia> Base.displaysize(IOBuffer())
(24, 80)

julia> Base.displaysize()
(24, 80)
```

This is called in the full `show()` method for showing arrays at the REPL:
[`show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", X::AbstractArray)`](https://github.com/NHDaly/julia/blob/879fef402835c1727aac52bafae686b5913aec2d/base/arrayshow.jl#L314), inside `print_matrix`, here:

```
    if !get(io, :limit, false)
        screenheight = screenwidth = typemax(Int)
    else
        sz = displaysize(io)
        screenheight, screenwidth = sz[1] - 4, sz[2]
    end
```

https://github.com/NHDaly/julia/blob/879fef402835c1727aac52bafae686b5913aec2d/base/arrayshow.jl#L159-L164

Note though that in that function, `io` is actually an `IOContext`, so as @Fengyang Wang describes in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40794864/751061, you can also manually set the `displaysize` on the IOContext if you want to control it yourself (updated for julia 1.0):

```
julia> show(IOContext(stdout, :limit=>true, :displaysize=>(10,10)), MIME("text/plain"), rand(1_000_000))
1000000-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.5684598962187111
 0.2779754727011845
 0.22165656934386813
 ⋮
 0.3574516963850929
 0.914975294703998
```

---

Finally, to close the loop, displaying a value at the REPL turns into `show(io, MIME("text/plain"), v)`, via `display`:
https://github.com/NHDaly/julia/blob/879fef402835c1727aac52bafae686b5913aec2d/base/multimedia.jl#L319

Answer (score 1):

If you want the setting to stick around in your REPL session:

```
Base.active_repl.options.iocontext[:displaysize] = (100, 80)
```

That will tell Julia to use 100 lines and 80 columns. You can go back to the default with:

```
Base.active_repl.options.iocontext[:displaysize] = displaysize(stdout)
```

To change the display size for a single call to `show`, you can do as others have suggested:

```
show(IOContext(stdout, :limit=>true, :displaysize=>(100,80)),
     MIME("text/plain"),
     thing)
```